# ¿Cómo coloco el codigo JS para que no se recargue la página al enviar un formulario que actualiza la cantidad del carrito de compras?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**html** Este es el codigo html del formulario:

```
<form id="cantidadform" method="post" action="actualizarcantidad.php">
  <input type="submit" id="menos" name="menos" value="-">
  <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidadInput" value=" <?php echo $product['cant_cart']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="idcart" name="id_cart" value=" <?php echo $producto['id_cart']; ?> ">
  <input type="submit" id="mas" name="plus" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="+">
</form>
```

**actualizarcantidad.php** La accion del formulario PHP es aumentar o disminuir la cantidad y actulizarla en la tabla del carrito de compras en la base de datos MYSQL. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php   
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidadInput'];
    $id_cart = $producto['id_cart'];
    $id_cart_post = $_POST['id_cart'];
    if ($id_cart_post==$id_cart) {   
      if (isset($_POST['menos'])) {
        if ($cantidad!=$producto['product_cant']) {
          $cantidad++;
        }else{
          $cantidad;
        }
      } else {
        $cantidad;
      }
     if (isset($_POST['mas'])) {
        if ($cantidad > 1) {
          $cantidad--;
        }else{
          $cantidad;
        }
      } else {
        $cantidad;
      }   
      $statement= $conexion->prepare("UPDATE cart SET cant_cart=:cantidad WHERE id_cart=:id_cart");
      $statement->execute(array(':cantidad' => $cantidad,':id_cart'=>$id_cart,));      
    }
  }
?>
```

**.js** estoy probando con este código ajax pero no funciona, es decir, se sigue recargando la pagina al darle en los botones de aumentar o disminuir cantidad.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cantidadform").bind("submit",function(){
        var cantidad = $("#cantidad");
        var idcart = $("#idcart");
        $.ajax({
            url:"actualizarcantidad.php",
            method:"POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data:{cantidad:cantidad, idcart:idcart},
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Cambia los input de tipo `submit` a tipo `button`.

Comment: Solo necesitas recibir el evento como parámetro `$("#cantidadform").bind("submit",function(event){` y, cancelarlo dentro de la función con `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

En la etiqueta form llamas a la función ej: ejecutar en el submit y le envías el evento como parámetro, también elimina el action y el method porque lo harás por ayax, quedaría algo así:

```
<form id="cantidadform" onsubmit="ejecutar(event)">
```

Luego en los input se suele utilizar el mismo id que name, y lo mismo utilizarías del lado de php al capturarlos y el mismo en los key del objeto que envías en la llamada ajax.

En el Script quedaría así:

```
function ejecutar(event) {
    event.preventDefault() // Con esto evitamos que se recargue la página
  var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
  var idcart = $("#idcart").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "actualizarcantidad.php",
    method: "POST",
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    data: { cantidad: cantidad, idcart: idcart },
  });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probare